# Is the "also" in the following sentence unnecessary?

Tags: grammar

This is the sentence:

> Ironically, the very thing that killed her was **also** the only thing
>   that remained of her.

If so, why?

Comment: It is not grammatically necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is unnecessary, but not incorrect.

In this case the author is using the word also to add emphasis to the irony of the situation by highlighting the fact that both clauses apply to the "thing."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's not a mistake to put it there. Try it yourself:

> Ironically, the very thing that killed her was **also** the only thing that remained of her.
>
> Ironically, the very thing that killed her was the only thing that remained of her.